# How can i submit my form whenever device connect to internet

Tags: android

I want to create an app where user can submit his information through a simple form. Now if user is not connected to internet than it should cache data and whenever user connects to internet it start uploading that data without notifying the user.

Any help?

Comment: you can listen to the connection state changes with a broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0):

Use this Receiver it will help you to submit the form when device is online

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "NetworkChangeReceiver";
    private boolean isConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
        isNetworkAvailable(context);
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        if (!isConnected) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet available via Broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isConnected = true;
                            // do your processing here ---
                            // if you need to post or get any data to the server 
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");

        isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }


}
```

let Me know if it works for you or any other issue in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `BroadcastReceiver` that will catch network changes and start your upload service:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String EXTRA_DATA_NAME_NETWORK_CONNECTED = "my.package.name.NetworkConnected";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(UploadService.ACTION_NETWORK_STATUS, null, context, UploadService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA_NAME_NETWORK_CONNECTED, isNetworkConnected(context));
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Method for network connectivity:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```